# Select two independent tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,price FROM herbs an WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
    $obj = $results->fetch_object();
```

This is my code I want to get the two table form the database which is "herbs" and "fruits" and update my shopping cart.

How can I select two table product_name, price from two independent tables?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Your title says 3 tables, your question says 2 tables, which is it? What do you want to do with all these tables? Maybe you want a UNION?

Comment: i have eddied the question sorry for the mistake i have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use either an `inner join` or an `outer join`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Or possibly a `union`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL)#UNION_operator

Comment: He says they're independent, my guess is he wants a UNION.

Comment: I was just thinking that myself, it's hard to say without more details but I think you are right - I've added union as well to the answer.